# solving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\alpha y\cdot e^{-\alpha\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, approximate-integration

Trying to solve the following integral,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{\alpha y\cdot e^{-\alpha\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}dx $$
where $\alpha$ is a constant.

this is an integral over $dx$ of the partial derivative of the original function
$ 1-e^{-\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ by $dy$:

$$ \frac{d(1-e^{-\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})}{dy} $$

Thanks!

Comment: Users like to see context for a problem. Why is this integral important to you, what were you looking into when this integral arose, etc, as well as any efforts you have put into the question so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=y\sinh t$ [leads](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E9) to the modified Bessel's (a.k.a. Macdonald's) [$K_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1): assuming $\alpha,y>0$, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-\alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha y\cosh t}\,dt=2K_0(\alpha y).$$

Comment: Correct: a $2$ is missing: $$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-\alpha  y \cos (t)} \, dt=2 K_0(\alpha  y)$$

Comment: @Raffaele: Fixed, thanks!